# Create Entity Class from Remote Database (through connection)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, cloudbees, entity-bean

I am using Netbeans 7.3.1, working on CloudBees host infrastructure (JBoss 7).

In the Services panel, I have created a connection to the remote MySQL database. I also added the `persistence.xml` information provided in CloudBees management page into EJB module project.

[image]

I want to create EJB Entity class but because it is remote resource, Netbeans cannot understand it at development time (no local database is present).

[image: No datasource for entity class]

Is there anyway to generate a Entity Class from a Service's connection, or create datasource from that connection?

Answer (score 0):

looks more like a NetBeans question. Any JavaEE application using a JNDI datasource will have the same issue